# Why is there a gap under my canvas

Tags: css, html

My fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/kpdgQ/16/

Why is there a vertical scrollbar with a little space under the orange canvas?

```
<div>
    <canvas></canvas>
</div>

div {   
    height:100%;
    width:100%;   
    background:blue;
}
canvas {
    background-color: orange;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}

html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed,
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend adding your HTML to the question, just to make the fiddle an added benefit, rather than a requirement. Otherwise you might get some close votes

Comment: but the html is there...

Comment: yeah, didn't notice that. Perhaps breaking it out would be helpful then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Canvas has display:inline by default.. When you change it to display:block it should display fine.. (the same case is with all images..)

Answer (score 0):

As @Mag said you can add display:block or set the float property. Also you can add overflow:hidden to the div enclosing the canvas tag.

Answer (score 0):

The css is changed to :

```
canvas {
    background-color: orange;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kpdgQ/18/